# Filtering non-XML data from a CLOB column

Tags: xml, db2, clob, zos

I am trying to select values from a `CLOB` (or `VARCHAR`) and apply `XMLQUERY` to it. The column contains a mix of XML and non-XML string data, and there doesn't seem to be an obvious way of filtering out non-XML rows.

I'm looking for an way to have `XMLPARSE` fail gracefully i.e. return `NULL` upon hitting non-XML data instead of failing the whole query.

1) `XMLPARSE` with valid XML

```
SELECT XMLPARSE('<?xml version="1.0"?><doc/>') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
1    
------
<doc/>
```

2) `XMLPARSE` with invalid XML

```
SELECT XMLPARSE('<?xml version="1.0"?><doc/>badxml') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
[Error Code: -20398, SQL State: 2200M]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-20398, 
SQLSTATE=2200M, SQLERRMC=27;An incorrect character was detected in the 
document RC=000C,RSN=3062., DRIVER=4.12.55
```

**Is there a way to add a function, `SET` or other parameter that would make the above return `NULL` or an empty result set?**

Comment: I can't test my theory out as I only have access to DB2 on an IBM i which uses different syntax and has other subtle differences. However, I would wrap this in a UDF and catch this error and return null when it occurs.

Comment: I have an ugly workaround. I'm using SQL-generating query that generates a separate statement for each row of the database: `SELECT 'SELECT XMLPARSE(clob_col) FROM clobtable WHERE 
clob_key = ''' || clob_key || ''';' FROM clobtable`
Then I feed the above results into a SQL batch and look for failed statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are in a rock and a hard place.  The only way to gracefully and efficiently use XMLPARSE and XMLQUERY is on known XML data.  Otherwise, as you have seen, they puke all over the place in a very ungraceful manner.

You could write a (or use an existing) very simple XML parser (they are super easy) and embed it in a user defined function that would verify that you have a well-formed XML document in the column and return the XML string on NULL.

Then you the user defined function to subquery the data before passing it to XMLPARSE/XMLQUERY.  Instead of returning NULL, you might want to return an empty document to make your life a little easier, but that depends on they queries you plan to apply.

Just food for thought, this problem goes away if you use the XML data type instead of CLOBs and VARCHARs, so if your table is small enough, can you select candidate rows and load them into a temporary table with a strongly typed XML column?